# Inverse of a matrix defined by a function

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations

I have a matrix $M$ whose elements are defined by some function
$$M_{ij} = f ( |i-j| ) $$

Is it possible to derive a function which defines the elements of the matrix inverse $M^{-1}$ i.e.

$$M^{-1}_{ij} = g(i,j) $$

in terms of the original function $f ( |i-j| ) $ , either in general or for some particularly helpful form of $f$? I have some freedom over $f$ but it would be helpful for it to be a spline.

Thanks.

Comment: I highly doubt it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem of inverting a [Toeplitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix). Its inverse is not Toeplitz in general. Search for "inverse of Toeplitz matrix" on the net.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, this should at least improve the efficiency of my inversion.